# Syntax highlighting rule to highlight the function reference in a Lisp function call

Tags: regex, vim, clojure, lisp, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a syntax highlighting rules in Vim for Clojure, or another Lisp where `(fn ...)` occurs mostly for function calls. I'm stuck at highlighting the first word of a function call, i.e. the function reference. Below is a demo of where I'm at:

[image: Wrong lisp syntax highlighting]

As you can see, the first word in the function calls (`str` in `(str a b c d)`) is highlighted. However, the first element in the literal lists (`1` in `'(1 2 3)`) is also highlighted, which is unintentional. To emphasize, both literal lists have their first elements highlighted, which is wrong.

Below is the syntax rule that does this highlighting:

```
syn match lispFunc "'\{0}\((\)\@<=\<.\{-1,}\>?\{0,1}"
```

Here's how I understand this rule:

- `'\{0}`: the character `'` must match 0 times;
- `\((\)\@<=`: the character `(` must match, but not be captured;
- `\<.\{-1,}\>`: this matches one word (`\<` and `\>` represent beginning and end of a word);
- `?\{0,1}`: if there is a `?` character at the end of the word, then consider it part of the word: e.g. the highlighted `?` in `list?` in the picture.

I've experimented quite a bit, but I can't seem to make the first two sub-rules work together.

Comment: This is probably just doomed: what is `(destructuring-bind (a b) c ...)` going to do?

Comment: or `(let (a b c) ...)`

Comment: @tfb well thanks for the input, but I'm focusing on Lisps that reserve `()` for function calls. Clojure is very well behaved in this sense, Racket a bit less so, but I prefer the noise that this will generate, over the noise of dictionary based function highlighting.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis Clojure does not really reserve parens (you can still define macros that use parens as binding forms, for example), and there are exceptions even in the core language (e.g. multi-arity defn); it is even more difficult to know what a bracket mean (binding, vector, code);

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis: perhaps you should reword the question: I assumed you were interested  'generic lisps', which was obviously not correct.

Comment: Try `syn match lispFunc "\(\('\)\@<!(\)\@<=\<.\{-1,}\>?\{0,1}"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, that worked. Feel free to submit it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: > *I'm focusing on Lisps that reserve () for function calls* I.e. not classic MacCarthy Lisp, ANSI Lisp, nor any of it ancestors like MacLisp or InterLisp, nor Scheme, nor Emacs Lisp, EuLisp, ISLisp ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
syn match lispFunc "\(\('\)\@<!(\)\@<=\<.\{-1,}\>?\{0,1}"
```

Here, `\(\('\)\@<!(\)\@<=` is a positive lookbehind that matches a `(` only if it is not preceded with `'`. This condition is set with a `\('\)\@<!` *negative* lookbehind inside the positive lookbehind.